# What condition handles the event that no MySQL records match an SQL statement?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, conditional-statements

I intend for the following code to display an 'h2' tag and text (displayed in the else statement at the bottom of the code) if there are no recorders that meet the SQL statement for a MySQL table property 'isVisible' == 1.

I decided to test to see if the query returned a 'null' result, this must be where I have a flaw in my logic. The result of my query must still be returning a value other than null even though none of the records match the "WHERE isVisible = 1" part of the SQL statement.

I only have one record in the DB hard coded to '0'. When the 'isVisible' property is returned to a value of '1' then the code executes properly. The exception is the only thing causing me trouble. I don't usually work with PHP much, so I am sure I probably just testing the wrong condition at the first if statement a few lines down.

Thanks for your time and help.

```
<?php

            // Generate SQL Statements
            $sql_position = "SELECT * FROM tbl_experience
                                WHERE isVisible = 1
                                ORDER BY 'displayPosition'";

            // Run Query
            $result = mysql_query($sql_position);

            // Iteration Variable
            $i = 0;

            if ($result != null) {

                // List all of the experiences as a timeline
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                    // Build a div to contain the experience properties
                    echo "<div id='experienceContainer_" . $row['displayPosition'] . "' class='experienceContainer";

                    if (i % 2) {
                        // The row should be displayed with 'Even' class attributes
                        echo " Even";
                    } else {
                        // The row should be displayed with 'Odd' class attributes
                        echo " Odd";
                    }

                    // Finish the opening <div> tag
                    echo "'>";


                        // Display the attributes of the experience
                        // Experience Type
                        echo "<div id='type_" . $row['displayPosition'] . "' class='experienceType'>";
                        switch ($row['type']) {
                            case 0:
                                    echo "Undefined";
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    echo "Work";
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    echo "Achievement";
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    echo "Award";
                                    break;
                        }
                        echo "</div>";

                        // Experience Title
                        echo "<div id='title_" . $row['displayPosition'] . "' class='experienceTitle'>";
                        echo $row['title'];
                        echo "</div>";

                        // Experience Description
                        echo "<div id='description_" . $row['displayPosition'] . "' class='experienceDescription'>";
                        echo $row['description'];
                        echo "</div>";

                    // Close the 'experienceContainer' div
                    echo "</div><!-- end of experienceContainer_" . $row['displayPosition'] . " -->";

                }
            } else {

                // There are no visible records
                echo "<h2>No entries for \"Experience\" can be found</h2>";

            }
```

Comment: [Blah blah better tutorial blah blah MYSQLi...](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

Comment: $result = query worked, it says nothing about the number of rows returned,

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, (mysql_num_row($result) != 0) worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `mysql_num_rows`

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

this if condition will guarantee that you will be routed to the `else` condition when there is no rows to display.